# boost asio giving You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options on cygwin

Tags: c++, boost, cygwin, boost-asio

I was trying to use the boost library first time. Using as an environment Eclipse 4.3 with CDT and as compiler gcc 3.4 and boost 1.53.

I was browsing various sites to find info on how to setup boost, but it doesn't seem to work. When I compile trying to include boost/asio.hpp I get the error:

```
You must add -D__USE_W32_SOCKETS to your compiler options
```

However, I don't want to use windows sockets, I want to use posix, so I don't really know what is wrong. As I need the project to run on HP-UX later, I dont want to get to Windows specific. If I use now windows sockets will the program later be easily portable to Unix, or are all the details encapsulated in boost, and I don't have to care anyway?

I tested a simple testprogram using FOREACH loop to confirm that boost itself works, and this is the case.

I also found this: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7881  so does it mean that this problem is currently currently not supported, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Windows Sockets API is based on Berkeley Sockets... you can write code that runs on both without any changes except for calling `WSAStartup` or not.  Of course, you should stick to `recv` and `accept` etc. and not use the `WSARecv` or `WSAAccept` versions.

Comment: That is what I'm currently doing. One reason why I use cygwin, to stay more true to the Unix path. However, if I want to use boost, I dont want get nasty surprises. :) Especially as I I'm trying to get comfortable with it and never used it before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems what you're trying to do is not supported by the library, the [documentation states](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html) the following under supported platforms

> The following platforms and compilers have been tested:
>
> - Win32 and Win64 using Visual C++ 7.1 and Visual C++ 8.0.
> - Win32 using MinGW.
> - Win32 using Cygwin. (**__USE_W32_SOCKETS must be defined.**)
> - Linux (2.4 or 2.6 kernels) using g++ 3.3 or later.
> - Solaris using g++ 3.3 or later.
> - Mac OS X 10.4 using g++ 3.3 or later.

added emphasis is mine. If that's not possible, you might try the patch suggested in the [linked ticket](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7881). However, grepping through the source code I see several occurrences of `#if !defined(BOOST_WINDOWS) && !defined(__CYGWIN__)` so it's not obvious that simply patching `io_service.hpp` will resolve anything. You might try adding `-U__CYGWIN__` to your `CXXFLAGS`, though the cygwin toolchain may not like that.

Full disclosure: I am not a Windows guy so hopefully someone else will chime in.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I wanted to look into today. If boost works also on HP-UX I guess I have to look through the code and see if I can find the appropriate switches. to make it behave as on Unix. I already tried that __CYGWIN__ define, but that alone doesn't help. It always is more complicated then using the obvious path ... *sigh*

Answer (score 1):

The `libboost-devel` package in the Cygwin distribution includes patches to not use Winsock on Cygwin in Boost.Asio.  I suggest trying that in conjunction with the gcc4 packages, which provide more recent versions of GCC.